What should `public-addr` be beyond the public ip/dns?
I think I am missing something about how Substrate is interacting with libp2p.
Base question: When setting the public-addr parameter for a parachain and internal relay chain node, I have found that sometimes it needs to have a /ws/ and other times not. When should it/why does it/how do I know how to properly structure the the public-addr?
Details:

Root Part (all OK as far as I know): /dns4/node.example.com/tcp/<port aka 30333 or 30334> or /ip4/123.1.2.3/tcp/<port aka 30333 or 30334>
Appears that parachain chain doesn't require a /ws aka /dns4/node.example.com/tcp/30333
Appears that relay chain might require /ws aka /dns4/node.example.com/tcp/30334/ws

I tested with various ways to connect to the node via libp2p, but perhaps all my logic is wrong.
